# Rails Create 302 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, http-status-code-302

I am working on a toy web app to practice Ruby on Rails, and I've run into an issue that I haven't been able to figure out in the documentation.  Essentially, I have a form to create tasks and relate them to users, but the form is issuing a 302 error when submitted and the record is not being saved.

I have two models, User and Task
User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tasks
end
```

Task

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :article
end
```

The idea is simple, a user can have many tasks.  The migrations for these are working fine.

I have created a (partial) form for creating tasks:

_compact_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for( [@currentUser, @currentUser.tasks.build] ) do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :label %>
    <%= f.text_field :label %>
    <%= f.label :complete %>
    <%= f.check_box :complete%>

    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

and this is attached to a dashboard view, which is trivially wired up to a dashboard controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @currentUser = User.find(1)
    end
end
```

All pretty straightforward so far.  My tasks controller has a few methods to manage creation so far.

Tasks controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def show 
        @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    end

    def create
        @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
        @task = @user.tasks.create( task_params )

        redirect_to '/'

    end

    private
    def task_params
        params.require(:task).permit(:label, :complete)
    end
end
```

And now we're at the point where I get confused.  I've manually inserted a task into my database and I'm able to retrieve it just fine, but for some reason, my create route is giving an HTTP 302 error.  I have set up my routes like so:

```
  resources :users do 
      resource :tasks
  end

  root 'dashboard#index'
  get 'dashboard/index'
```

and rake routes outputs

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
 new_user_tasks GET    /users/:user_id/tasks/new(.:format)  tasks#new
edit_user_tasks GET    /users/:user_id/tasks/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
     user_tasks GET    /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format)      tasks#show
                PATCH  /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format)      tasks#update
                PUT    /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format)      tasks#update
                DELETE /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format)      tasks#destroy
                POST   /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format)      tasks#create
          users GET    /users(.:format)                     users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)                     users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                 users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)            users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                 users#show
                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                 users#update
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                 users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                 users#destroy
           root GET    /                                    dashboard#index
dashboard_index GET    /dashboard/index(.:format)           dashboard#index
```

so the create route appears to be there, and it appears to be correct.

Now for the strangest part!  If I use my form, this is what I see in the console:

```
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
```

This appears to be the correct code in my tasks#create method, so I'm pretty confused where the data is going.  Can anyone shed some light into next steps for debugging this?  I have spent some time creating different forms and working through the examples in [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide, but I seem to have made a mistake somewhere along the lines and I can't find it.

Comment: HTTP 302 means it is temporally redirecting, which is the correct behaviour since in your `create` method you are invoking `redirect_to '/'`.

Comment: And should that be removing the newly created record?  I should have added that the database is not being updated.

Comment: Can you post the params please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your redirection inside an `respond_to` block, redirects without format declaration cause 302 status responses because it doesn't know which kind of response to give for redirection, so it assumes your client would process the `location` header field that goes with the response, you should do something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to '/' }
end
```

302 status isn't an error, it is an indication of redirection and the redirected location is being sent as HTTP header. As far as model not being saved, you should provide better logs results, it could be a vast number of issues, like unpermitted params, validations, database error...

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because you made me realize that the problem couldn't be about the HTTP error.  The actual problem was in the model's declaration.  Notice in the code that I posted that Task is related to Article instead of User, which is a holdover from my last prototype that I forgot to change.  Unfortunately, the 302 surprised me and I went down a totally incorrect debugging path.